# C# - Concurrency access violation while updating MS Access table from DataGridView

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview

I'm having some trouble updating Access tables from a DataGridView.
What's confusing me is that the code beblow works with one table and not with another, but they both have the exact same structure.

## The tables

I have two tables with multiple (identical) fields, in which the primary key is a field called "Number" ; this field is Autoincrement, and indexed without duplicates, in both tables.
So I read about the lack of primary key as the origin of concurrency violation, but it doesn't seem to be the issue here.

## The code

Here is the relevant part of my code, gathered together :

#### Initialization

```cs
BindingSource BS = new BindingSource();
DbDataAdapter adapter;
DataTable table = new DataTable();
OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(query, odbcConnection);
OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(command);
adapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = true; // Attempt to fix the issue
adapter.AcceptChangesDuringFill = true; // same
DbCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new OdbcCommandBuilder(adapter);
dgv.DataSource = BS;
BS.DataSource = table;
adapter.Fill(table);
```

#### Saving the changes

```cs
OdbcCommandBuilder builder = new OdbcCommandBuilder((OdbcDataAdapter)adapter);
adapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand(); // Fix attempt
adapter.Update(table); // Where the exception is thrown
```

Considering my problem happens quite randomly depending on the database used, I think it's database related, but they got the same structure, and both are not in use (copied on my local drive) so I really don't have a clue what's happening.

Comment: have you checked the result of the `GetUpdateCommand` method? Also, check out [this post](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?479544-RESOLVED-OleDB-Concurrency-Violation-in-MS-access). Seems somewhat similar including the AutoIncrement field. Also, if it is AutoIncrement-related you may want to check out [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl/adodotnetdataset/thread/958e6d51-725a-4649-8fc0-79a831f8f37e)

Comment: Also, why are you using an `OdbcDataAdapter` instead of an `OledbDataAdapter`?

Comment: @nicholas : thank you for your answer, I sure had not looked into autoincrement values. But it seems the solution in these posts is really about adding rows, when my problem occurs at updating (where the identity field is already set to the right number, as it's used to find which row should be updated, am I right ?).
As a matter of fact the issue never occured while inserting a new row.

Comment: As for the OdbcDataAdapter, it's because I'm using a class from my company which wraps Odbc and Mysql to use both types indifferently. We should re-code it soon enough, and I'm curious about the advantages of OleDB over Odbc, it will need another thread (or an existing one) though I think.

Comment: Well, then have you compared the `adapter.UpdateCommand` between the tables that work and the tables that sometimes do not work?

Comment: I have compared them, their command text in both case is an update query on all the fields (except the PK) with a WHERE clause that applies to the PK, and has all other fields from the table. Although I can't see the value of the parameters, in the Parameters collection I only see objects with "Value" property set to null (but I think its normal since it's the case on the 'working' table too ?)

Comment: Hmm. Well that's all I can think of. I'll +1 this to hopefully draw more attention to it. My last vague ideas have to do with column data types. Try comparing the columns which are different between the working and non-working queries and see if there may be bad type-casting going on. The PK columns are defined the same? I was somewhat hinting along those lines with the Oledb question since Access's native engine is OleDb, but really, I am out of ideas.

Comment: I'll dig further in the column types, but regarding the PKs, yes they are exactly the same. Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I changed the corporate class to use OleDb instead of Odbc, worked like a charm !
The code remains exactly the same regarding the `DataGridView`, except `OdbcCommand` becomes `OleDbCommand` and `OdbcDataAdapter` becomes `OleDbDataAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there are relationships defined to other tables, which might prevent an update of a certain field.

Also, a table might contain Indexes or Expressions for checking the validity of data, which prevent updating the table.

Have you checked these possibilities?